# need a short idiom/phrase or word for two people/things that are complete opposites

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am trying to describe two people with opposite personalites and the sentence is structured so that I need the idiom/phrase to act like an adjective. The sentence is "... events of the summer intertwine the stories of 2 _____ drug dealers, 2 high school lifeguards..." I need a phrase that fits in the space that is short (i.e. 1-3 words) and makes the point that while they are both drug dealers they have complete opposite personalities and incentives. Basically I want something better than "dissimilar". It doesn't need to be this specific, but if it helps, one of the dealers is super chill and laid back to a fault while the other is super uptight and always in a hurry.

Comment: Two drug dealing lifeguards whose personalities are diametrically opposed [as different as night and day].

Answer (score 2):

[Chalk and cheese.](https://english-grammar-lessons.com/chalk-and-cheese-meaning/)

> When using the idiom “chalk and cheese,” you’re referring to two items, tasks, people, or ideologies that are entirely different from one another. The phrase still has a use today, and many people use it in informal and formal settings to describe differences.
>
> This idiom dates all the way back to the 13th century, and it remains relevant today. The “chalk” and the “cheese” can refer to many different items, people, ideologies, or any situation where you want to compare two opposites.

Bit of a cliché, though.

Comment: this is great. this is exactly the type of thing I am looking for. also, i've never heard anyone use this phrase so it doesn't sound cliche to me lol.

Comment: @Nick I suppose that the downside is that hardly anyone will know what you're talking about, at least if you have a U.S. audience. Perhaps the expression is better known elsewhere.

Comment: Would anyone even get Mutt and Jeff anymore?

Comment: Mutt and Jeff reprints frequently are discussed on the CIDU blog.  (Comics I Don't Understand)  Sometimes the regulars are able to  work out a meaning. Sometimes not.  https://cidu.info/tag/mutt-and-jeff/

Answer (score 0):

antipodal: The events of summer intertwine the stories of (two) antipodal drug dealers.

MW:
1: of or relating to the antipodes
specifically : situated at the opposite side of the earth or moon
an antipodal meridian
an antipodal continent
2: diametrically opposite
an antipodal point on a sphere
3: entirely opposed
a system antipodal to democracy